# how to show text of textbox in a group of four characters seperated by space without increasing the length in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to show text in a group of four `characters` separated by space in a `XamMaskedEditor` without increasing the length of original text. eg. my original text is `0000111100001111` but have to display `0000 1111 0000 1111`.

Is it possible?

If yes please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean, you want te select a different font size so the length will be the same or less?

Comment: Hi, I am using  XamMaskedEditor and want to show my text in group of four characters e.g: 0000 1111 0011 1100.

Comment: I think they're asking how to have the `.Text` set to "12345678" but display `1234 5678` (say, for auto-formatting a credit card number).

Comment: Ah so the display of the characters can be wider but the original string should not contain de spaces?

Comment: yes i want to achieve the same my original string is like "12345678" but want to show in XamMaskedEditor 1234 5678

Answer (score 0):

If your input is going to be of a static max length (such as 16 digit credit card numbers), you could use the DataMode property and set it to "Raw". With that the value of the text property will be the entered value without the padding.

```
<inf:XamMaskedEditor HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="150"
                     Mask="#### #### #### ####"
                     DataMode="Raw"
                     Text="{Binding TestTxt, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In the example above, your input would allow only numbers and look like:

1234 5678 9012 3456

But your text property's value would be;

1234567890123456

Answer (score 0):

Use this converter in your xaml, didn't test it but it should work just fine.

```
public class FourLetterGroupConverter : IValueConverter
{     
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var toConvert = (string)value;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < toConvert.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(toConvert[i]);

            if(i != 0 && i%4 ==0)
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```